# python signxml - InvalidDigest if there is a "xmlns" namespace declaration in the root element

Tags: python

I need to sign a XML file.
The signature process works in both cases (with and without the namespace declared in the root element), but the signature verification fails when there is the specific `xmlns` namespace declared.

Also, when I have less nested levels, then there is no error in both cases, but I need the nesting (the final XML file will have even more nested levels than this example).

The XML files need to be submitted to a government agency (Country Paraguay, SIFEN / EKUATIA, Sistema Nacional de Facturacion Electrónica) and the validation fails if I exclude the namespace from the file.

Here is my code to replicate the error; I am using `Ubuntu 20.04`, `Python 3.8.10`, `lxml==4.9.2` and `signxml==2.10.1`.

```py
def test(with_ns):
    print('### parsing XML from string')
    ns = ''
    if with_ns:
        ns = 'xmlns="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd"'
    cdc = '0123'*11
    root = etree.fromstring(
        '<rDE {} xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd/siRecepDE_v150.xsd">'
            '<dVerFor>1</dVerFor>'
            '<DE Id="{}">'
                '<dDVId>9</dDVId>'
                '<gOpeDE>'
                    '<iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>'
                '</gOpeDE>'
            '</DE>'
        '</rDE>'.format(ns, cdc))
    output_bytes = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
    print(output_bytes.decode())

    print()
    print('### signing XML')
    with open(os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'tb_pub_key.pem')) as f:
        pub_key = f.read()
    with open(os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'tb_priv_key.pem')) as f:
        priv_key = f.read()
    signer = signxml.XMLSigner(
        c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315')
    signer.namespaces = {
        None: signxml.namespaces.ds,
    }
    root = signer.sign(
        root,
        key=priv_key,
        cert=pub_key,
        reference_uri=cdc)
    output_bytes = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
    print(output_bytes.decode())

    print()
    print('### verifying signature')
    result = signxml.XMLVerifier().verify(
        root,
        ca_pem_file=os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'bundle-doc-mic.pem'))
    output_bytes = etree.tostring(result.signed_xml, pretty_print=True)
    print(output_bytes.decode())
```

The code runs successfully without the namespace:

```
>>> test(with_ns=False)
### parsing XML from string
<rDE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd/siRecepDE_v150.xsd">
  <dVerFor>1</dVerFor>
  <DE Id="01230123012301230123012301230123012301230123">
    <dDVId>9</dDVId>
    <gOpeDE>
      <iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
    </gOpeDE>
  </DE>
</rDE>
### signing XML
<rDE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd/siRecepDE_v150.xsd">
  <dVerFor>1</dVerFor>
  <DE Id="01230123012301230123012301230123012301230123">
    <dDVId>9</dDVId>
    <gOpeDE>
      <iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
    </gOpeDE>
  </DE>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
      <Reference URI="#01230123012301230123012301230123012301230123">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue>kKbZeA/kIplpYlTuynW8SsjEovYlkDW4JdiST9qH6s8=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</rDE>
### verifying signature
<DE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Id="01230123012301230123012301230123012301230123">
  <dDVId>9</dDVId>
  <gOpeDE>
    <iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
  </gOpeDE>
</DE>
```

But when adding the namespace, I get this error:

```
>>> test(with_ns=True)
### parsing XML from string
<rDE xmlns="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd/siRecepDE_v150.xsd">
  <dVerFor>1</dVerFor>
  <DE Id="01230123012301230123012301230123012301230123">
    <dDVId>9</dDVId>
    <gOpeDE>
      <iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
    </gOpeDE>
  </DE>
</rDE>
### signing XML
<rDE xmlns="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd/siRecepDE_v150.xsd">
  <dVerFor>1</dVerFor>
  <DE Id="01230123012301230123012301230123012301230123">
    <dDVId>9</dDVId>
    <gOpeDE>
      <iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
    </gOpeDE>
  </DE>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
      <Reference URI="#01230123012301230123012301230123012301230123">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue>1PsVs9lH4Yx0i/2ler3MaIUFP4R9yhTm6uksVkh72Sk=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</rDE>
### verifying signature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/331/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ralf/PycharmProjects/tb_system_01/base/sifen/base.py", line 111, in test_2
    result = signxml.XMLVerifier().verify(
  File "/home/ralf/PycharmProjects/tb_system_01/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/signxml/__init__.py", line 981, in verify
    raise InvalidDigest("Digest mismatch for reference {}".format(len(verify_results)))
signxml.exceptions.InvalidDigest: Digest mismatch for reference 0
```

Any ideas why this could be happening? Or how this could be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue in `signxml` GitHub with the same content of this question.

The devs over there classified the behavior in my code as a bug, and later released a fix (in v3.2.0).

See https://github.com/XML-Security/signxml/issues/225